# Forced cancellation of async wrapped sync task

Tags: c#, async-await

I have code which calls an external lib synchronous operation, which can take a very long time to finish. I can't rewrite this lib, and there is not a method to stop the operation. Is there any solution to stop this task after some timeout?

I have tried this code, but it does not work not as I expected. It awaits until the calculation is not completed.

How can I solve this task?

```
 private static async Task<ResultData> GetResultAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)); 
        try
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var result = ExternLib.Calculate(fileName);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    throw new CalculationException(fileName);
                }
                return result;
            },
                timeoutSource.Token
            ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            SomeCode(e);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            SomeCode2(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SomeCode3(e);
        }
        return await Task.FromResult<ResultData>(null).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: `return await Task.FromResult<ResultData>(null).ConfigureAwait(false);` -> `return null;`

Comment: @StephenCleary I know this. It's only case when one of exception has been catched. In normal case return statment inside try block will return right result.

Answer (score 1):

Create two tasks, one which does the work, and one which acts as a timer:

```
var workTask = Task.Run(() => // etc );
var timerTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

The wait for *either* task to complete:

```
var completedTask = Task.WaitAny(new[] { workTask, timerTask });
```

Then, if `completedTask` is the timer task, your timeout has expired, and you can take appropriate action: whether or not you can *stop* the long running task depends on how it's structured, but you do know you can stop waiting for it.

Comment: Nice approach - just need to be careful not to let the user mash the retry button a couple hundred times :)

Comment: thank you for this solution. It's not silver bullet, but it works)               @plast1k this method is called by some kind of non user caused event